# Dns.GetHostByName/Resolve Alias List is Empty

Tags: c#, .net-core, dns, .net-standard, cname

Why does the built-in C# DNS client no longer populate the `Aliases` array for the newer (non-deprecated) methods?

Example (csx / REPL):

```cs
using System.Net;
var domain = "mydomain.example.com";

Dns.Resolve(domain) // Warning: Deprecated
```

> ```
> > IPHostEntry { AddressList=IPAddress[1] { [1.2.3.4] }, Aliases=string[2] { "cname1.example.com", "cname2.example.com" }, HostName="myapp.hostname.example.net" }
> ```

```cs
Dns.GetHostByName(domain) // Warning: Deprecated
```

> ```
> > IPHostEntry { AddressList=IPAddress[1] { [1.2.3.4] }, Aliases=string[2] { "cname1.example.com", "cname2.example.com" }, HostName="myapp.hostname.example.net" }
> ```

```cs
Dns.GetHostEntry(domain)
```

> ```
> > IPHostEntry { AddressList=IPAddress[1] { [1.2.3.4] }, Aliases=string[0] { }, HostName="myapp.hostname.example.net" }
> ```

I know there are dependencies I can pull in that will retrieve the proper CNAME record list, but my question specifically is: **Why are there two deprecated methods that populate the `Aliases` array (with precisely the information that I need) when there is *not* a current (non-deprecated) method that provides the same functionality?**

And a bonus follow-up question: Other than the deprecation, is there any harm to still using `Dns.Resolve()`? Does it use an older protocol specification or similar, or is it just deprecated due to naming?

*(N.B. This dates back to around 2006 but I couldn't find a clear answer specifically regarding the **`Aliases`** array property.)*

Comment: Please do not use `1.2.3.4` as fake IP. If really needed, the equivalent of `example.com` is the IP block  `192.0.2.0/24`. See RFC5737 for all details.

Comment: I'm not really sure the wonderful folks over at APNIC care, but point taken. :)

Comment: The Internet community cares... See https://blog.cloudflare.com/fixing-reachability-to-1-1-1-1-globally/ for an explanation of what happens when people use IP addresses that are not theirs.